# how to insert an array of strings to sql query in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

I have this query in ruby:

```
  sql = "SELECT variants.id,
                      code,
                      regular_price,
                      price_before_sale
                FROM  variants
                WHERE variants.code IN (#{context.codes.join(",")})"
```

where `context.codes = ['PRDCT-1','PRDCT-2']`

now context.codes becomes `(PRDCT1,PRDCT2)` inside the sql query because of the `.join` but what I want to happen is `('PRDCT1','PRDCT2')` what am I missing?

EDI: I have tried to do `(#{context.codes.join("','")})` but it returns `(PRDCT1','PRDCT2)`

Comment: Did you consider using an ORM like [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/v6.0.0/activerecord) or [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel)? There are extremely helpful when it comes to build SQL queries and to sanitize them against SQL injection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do that. [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) is watching. Instead, provide the adequate number of placeholders:

```
sql = "SELECT variants.id,
                      code,
                      regular_price,
                      price_before_sale
                FROM  variants
                WHERE variants.code IN (#{context.codes.map { "?" }.join(",")})"
```

and then provide `*context.codes` in statement parameters.

Comment: I guess in this case, where the programmer has full control of what's stored in `context.codes`, it isn't that crucial. But it's a good practice nevertheless.

Answer (score -1):

I got it.
I added single quotes to `('#{context.codes.join("','")}')`

Comment: Adding the quotes to the separator seems a bit dirty. You should escape each value separately (according to the query syntax) and then join the results.